Getting the recursive relation of series
If I have a finite sum of some terms which are the product of the prefactor, function f[i,j,k,a,b,c], and the x^m y^n z^k. I want to shift the exponent to x^a y^b z^c.
For example
C0 a f[1,1,1,a,b,c] x^a y^b z^c +
 C1 a f[1,1,2,a,b,c] x^(a+1) y^b z^c +
 C2 b f[1,0,1,a,b,c] x^a y^(b+2) z^c +
 C3 f[1,2,1,a,b,c] x^(a-1) y^b z^(c+2)

I want to transform it to
C0 a f[1,1,1,a,b,c] x^a y^b z^c +
 C1 (a-1) f[1,1,2,a-1,b,c]x^a y^b z^c +
 C2 (b-2) f[1,0,1,a,b-2,c]x^a y^b z^c +
 C3 f[1,2,1,a+1,b,c-2]x^a y^b z^c 


I have edited your post to include an a multiplying the first term.  I believe this meant to be here. Reverse the edit if that's wrong, but if it is wrong, you'll have to explain the replacement rule more clearly.

If I understand the replacement, this should work:
expression /. expr_ x^(a + m_.) y^(b + n_.) z^(c + l_.) :> (expr /. {a -> a - m, b -> b - n, c -> c - l}) x^a y^b z^c

That is,
C0 a f[1, 1, 1, a, b, c] x^a y^b z^c + C1 a f[1, 1, 2, a, b, c] x^(a + 1) y^b z^c + C2 b f[1, 0, 1, a, b, c] x^a y^(b + 2) z^c + C3 f[1, 2, 1, a, b, c] x^(a - 1) y^b z^(c + 2);
expr = % /. expr_ x^(a + m_.) y^(b + n_.) z^(c + l_.) :> (expr /. {a -> a - m, b -> b - n, c -> c - l}) x^a y^b z^c
(* (-2 + b) C2 x^a y^b z^c f[1, 0, 1, a, -2 + b, c] + a C0 x^a y^b z^c f[1, 1, 1, a, b, c] + (-1 + a) C1 x^a y^b z^c f[1, 1, 2, -1 + a, b, c] + C3 x^a y^b z^c f[1, 2, 1, 1 + a, b, -2 + c] *)


You may define a somewhat complicated rule to achieve this:
rule = {f[1, 1, 2, a, b, c] :> 
    f[1, 1, 2, a - 1, b, c] (a - 1)/(a  x),  
   f[1, 0, 1, a, b, c] :> f[1, 0, 1, a, b - 2, c]  (b - 2)/(b   y^2), 
   f[1, 2, 1, a, b, c] :> f[1, 2, 1, a + 1, b, c - 2]  x/z^2 };

With this:
C0  a  f[1, 1, 1, a, b, c]  x^a  y^b  z^c + 
  C1  a  f[1, 1, 2, a, b, c]  x^(a + 1)  y^b  z^c + 
  C2  b  f[1, 0, 1, a, b, c]  x^a  y^(b + 2)  z^c + 
  C3  f[1, 2, 1, a, b, c]  x^(a - 1)  y^b  z^(c + 2) /. rule



It can only solve the simple cases. The number of terms is large.
